# Is there a way i can describe a Key Vault backed scope in Databricks to know which Key vault it is pointed to?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am looking for a way to find out the Key Vault URL backed by a Databricks [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes)

I have checked out documentation for Databricks [secrets CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/secrets-cli) as well as [dbutils.secrets](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/dbutils.html) but could not find one. How do we know the Key Vault name once the scope is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command lists the existing scopes `databricks/KeyVault` backend in a workspace using the CLI:

```
databricks secrets list-scopes
```

**Note:** You can find the Key Vault Name on the KeyVault URL associated with the scope as shown below:

[image]

If you need complete key names associated with the scope name, you can use the below command:

```
databricks secrets list --scope chepra
```

[image]